# Inserting Image in Wordml generated from a xsl

Tags: image, xslt, openxml, docx, wordml

I need some tips and examples for the following task:

I have a image data somewhere on my disk ... this data can be of type .svg/.bmp/.gif/.png ... lets say for the moment that all of them are of type .svg.

My task is to insert several of these image data in soecific places of the WordML that I am generating.

The generation of WordML is working superbly, but as I have NEVER before read or heard about inserting image data in wordML data ... I am kinda lost.

I am going forward with `<maml:medialink>` and `<maml:image>`.

Would be really nice of you, if anyone can give me a little introduction and support with this new venture of mine.

Thank you.

Jasmin

Comment: Not XSLT related but WordML Vocabulary.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for the correction Alejandro. Yeap, WordML it is ... and I found commands like <w:pict> etc, but haven't still found a concrete exmaple/tutorial.

Comment: you will certainly find something on the spec. Have you tried?